# Query in which Start_date of two tables do not match in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables `per_asg` and `xx_asg`, they have same no. of columns and should ideally have same no. of data.

**per_asg**:

```
person_id   start_date   end_date
-------------------------------------------
1           01-jan-2016  07-jan-2016
1           02-feb-2016  08-march-2016
```

**xx_per_asg**

```
person_id   start_date   end_date
-------------------------------------
1           01-jan-2016  07-jan-2016
1           02-feb-2016  08-march-2016
1           03-feb-2016  04-sep-2016
```

As seen on xx_per_asg there is one extra row with start_date `'03-feb-2016'` and end_date `'04-sep-2016'.` I wrote a query to fetch such rows but I am not getting the extra rows completly :

```
select start_date 
from xx_per_asg xx_per_asg, per_asg pa
where xx_per_asg.person_id = pa.person_id
  and xx_per_asg.start_date <> pa.start_date
```

But this will still the entire set of data

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each table may have rows that are not in the other table, and you need to find both kinds, something like this should work. Assuming neither tables has duplicate rows (for example, that would be true if they each have primary keys), then if you do a `union all` of the two tables, the rows that exist in both tables will be duplicates in the union. Those that are not in both tables will not be duplicated. So after the `union all` we can group by all columns and use a `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` condition to find the rows that are only in one table but not in the other.

A small tweak to this will also tell us which table has the "unpaired" row, for each row. In the solution, I use `max(source)` (because we shouldn't group by "source", so we need to use an aggregate function on it), but it's really a `max()` over a single value; it will just be that value.

This solution is efficient, because it does not use joins and it does not use an expensive `MINUS` operation (or, actually, two `MINUS` operations and also reading each table twice instead of once, if the assignment was to find unpaired rows from both tables, not just from one).

```
select max(source), person_id, start_date, end_date
from   ( select 'per_asg'    as source, person_id, start_date, end_date from per_asg
         union all
         select 'xx_per_asg' as source, person_id, start_date, end_date from xx_per_asg
       )
group by person_id, start_date, end_date
having count(*) = 1
order by person_id, start_date, end_date    --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

One more thing - if you compare by `start_date`, you must be sure all dates are "pure dates" (with no time-of-day component); that is, the time component should be `00:00:00`. Is that the case? If it isn't, all solutions will need to be adjusted (and will become less efficient, that is more time-consuming).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the extra rows, I would expect a query more like this:

```
select xx.*
from xx_per_asg xx
where not exists (select 1
                  from per_asg pa
                  where pa.person_id = xx.person_id and
                        pa.start_date = xx.start_date
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If,  as it seems in the example,  the rows that are in both tables are equal, field by field,  you could do:

```
 select * from xx_per_asg
  minus
 select * from per_asg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select xx.startdate,xx.enddate,xx.person_id from xx_per_asg xx
LEFT OUTER JOIN per_asg per on per.person_id = xx.person_id
Where xx.start_date <> per.start_date
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work.  If you have 2 rows with dates D1 and D2 on both tables t1 and t2, they would appear in the result set as t1.D1<>t2.D2 and t2.D1<>t1.D2.